# how to use $_GET with this url format site.com/extension/rar

Tags: php, get

I am seeing this url format at most websites.

```
site.com/extension/rar
```

I wonder how they get the value='rar' using $_GET.

What I know is that $_GET can be use in here

```
site.com/extension/index.php?ext=rar
```

Now I wanted to change my way of calling a variable.

I wanted to apply what most websites do.

How can I call variable in the former?

Comment: You would be using rewrites, the configuration varies a bit depending what web server you are using.

Comment: it depends on you hosting site on how they handle get variables

Comment: You cant get the that part of the url using $_GET

Comment: Url rewriting is the concept you should research.

Comment: Check out this link, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/7945816/1134705 and check out more .htaccess tricks here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works to get the "rar":

```
$name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I most likely being done using .htaccess

It is an Apache module that allows you "rewrite" urls at the engine level based on your own set of rules. So basically it rewrites URLs on the fly.

So, in your example you could have a file named .htaccess with the following contents: (there may be other options)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^extension/([a-z0-9]+)$    somefile.php?extension=$1    [L]
```

Basically, you are saying: If someone is looking for a URL that looks like "extension/somenumbers-and-letters" then show the contents of "somefile.php?extension=whatever-those-number-and-leters-are".

Do a search on Apache mod_rewrite to find more information.