# .htaccess rewrite GET variables w/ 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to simultaneously do a 301 redirect and imporve my url structure by stripping the get variables.

I recently updated my website and Google has some old pages cached that have since moved. The structure looks like this

```
wwww.domain.com/locations.asp?zip=10001 <---OLD URL
wwww.domain.com/locations/?zip=10001 <---NEW URL
```

Right now I'm redirecting the old page to the new using the following line in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /solar_panel_systems_zip.asp /zip-code/
```

The above works fine but I'd like the URL to be as follows:

```
wwww.domain.com/locations/zip/10001
```

I came across this post [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables) and tried this rule but no luck :/

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

I'm assuming this is because I'm 301 redirecting and doing a rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^locations/zip/([0-9]+)$ /locations/?zip=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will make it so when someone requests `http://www.domain.com/locations/zip/10001`, they will get served the contents of `/locations.php?zip=10001`.

To redirect the old URLs to the new ones, you will need to also add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /locations(\.asp)?/?\?zip=([0-9]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /locations/zip/%3?%4 [L,R=301]
```

So when someone tries to go to `http://www.domain.com/locations.asp?zip=10001` **or** `http://www.domain.com/locations/?zip=10001`, they get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/locations/zip/10001`.

Comment: the 2nd block worked great but the first block is giving me a bit of trouble. Perhaps its because my file isn't locations.php its /locations/?zip= ??? (wordpress page)

Comment: To clarify right now I get redirected to -> http://www.domain.com/locations/zip/10001 but that page isn't found because it's not serving up the php file

Comment: @user1647347 Just change the target of the first rule to `/locations/` then

Comment: I think thie problem is with "RewriteRule ^locations/zip/([0-9]+)$ /locations/?zip=$1 [L,QSA]"

It's hard because wordpress will show the page regardless but I keep landing at http://www.domain.com/locations/zip/10001 but the 10001 data is not showing up. When I visit http://www.domain.com/locations/?zip=10001 the data does show up

Comment: @user1647347 if this is wordpress trying to figure out what to load, it's going to look at the `REQUEST_URI` and see something it doesn't recognize (e.g. `/locations/zip/10001`). You'll have to either use wordpress to handle the redirects or you can try internally proxying by adding a `P` to the flags: `[L,QSA,P]`