# Clean/Simple URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I have a HTML form which looks like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" maxlength="16">
</form>
```

The process.php spits out some data, that's all working fine. When it has returned the data the URL looks like this:

```
website.com/process.php?q=banana
```

I would like to have a cleaner URL like this:

```
website.com/banana/
```

Is this possible using .htaccess? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this question has been answered so many times : 

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7945816/2858417)

Comment: No, the request is to directly create an SEO-looking URL, not how to decode an SEO URL into a dynamic URL.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+process\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /process.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use method="post" to hide the Query String in the URL. I can't think of any way to dictate the format of the URI when using a form submission, but maybe someone else can come up with something.