# htaccess rewrite url and redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am wondering how to rewrite this url `profile.php?user=1` to `/user/1`.
I know that this can be done by .htaccess. Here is what i have tried and it worked fine but the only problem is that it

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Besides these codes, my .htacces also has these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -Indexes 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?pagename=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?pagename=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please also tell me if my .htaccess page is correct. I am not good at htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

Comment: no that page dosent answer my question please answer it here -lease

Comment: "but the only problem is that it..."??? what is the problem?

Comment: i want to re wright the url from profile.php?user=1 to /user/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure the page has either absolute links or add this to the page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

otherwise, all your links will be broken.

Comment: the page directs to user/1 but there the page says 404 error.. any idea ?

Comment: @anamika the second rule captures everything that starts with `/user/`

Answer (score 0):

In htacess rewrite you want to in fact redirect a url structure to a different url

If you have a link to profile.php?user=1 you will have to change this like to this : `profile.php/user/1` then tell your htacess to redirect this adresse to this `profile.php?user=1`

You can do this :

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$        index.php?&user=$1
```

If you want to test out some htaccess I will recomande this usedul site : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/