# php $_GET two variables rewirte to subdomain htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple php and htaccess question.

I have this $_GET :

```
if(isset($_GET['word'])) {
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

  }
}
```

So the url will be :

```
example.com/index.php?word=test&id=555
```

Now, i want to convert the url to :

```
test.example.com/555/
```

i have a htaccess code like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)word=[^&]+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?word=%1 [QSA,L]
```

But it is just for one variable, not both of them.

How can i do that with htaccess ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^word=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}/%2/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```