# Using htaccess to rewrite URL with GET variable to page title

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a URL like:

```
http://example.com/shop/item.php?id=2
```

To something like:

```
http://example.com/shop/my-page-title-2.html
```

Because of the possibility of having multiple items with the same page title, I want to add the ID to the URL, as each ID is unique and will ensure I do not have any duplicate URL's.

The page title should also be rewritten so that everything is in lowercase for the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

Comment: @user2662639 While this question has most likely been asked before, that isn't a very good duplicate.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this, usually it is rewritten the opposite way.

Comment: @TinyGiant I want to rewrite the URL like this for SEO purposes, to have keywords in the URL.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to your intentions. `mod_rewrite` changes the followed url, it does not change the url visible to the browser, so this would not change what is seen for SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop/item.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /my-page-title-%1\.html? [NC,R,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^my-page-title-([^.]+)\.html$ /shop/item.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```