# .htaccess rewriting PHP file with parameter?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I basically have a file like this:

```
user.php
```

It has different get Parameters:

```
user.php?method=GetUserData
user.php?method=SetUserData
```

I want to call it according to REST like this:

```
server.com/GetUserData
server.com/SetUserData
```

Is this possible?

Comment: yeah it is possible using `.htaccess` .. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?method=/$1 [NC]` ref : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate version of Pogrindis' solution would be to add the following to a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([GS]etUserData)$ user.php?method=/$1 [NC]
```

This works if these are the only two methods you need to set — as the regex pattern matches only `"GetUserData"` and `"SetUserData"`.

This prevents other base links (such as http://server.com/MyPage) from being converted as well.