# .htaccess : Rewrite url, one variable to directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to know if this final result can be achieved with some htaccess rules.

On the **config** folder. Where * is the page's name to show as folder.

```
/projectdir/config/?p=* or /projectdir/config/index.php?p=*
to /projectdir/config/*/
```

Example

```
/projectdir/config/?p=page1 => /projectdir/config/page1/
/projectdir/config/index.php?p=page1 => /projectdir/config/page1/
```

I tried the code posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables) question, but without results

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

> Which basically: http://localhost/index.php?page=controller To
>
> http://localhost/controller/

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: @starkeen i tried the code (the first code block) posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables) question, but without results

Comment: Please edit your question to post what you have tried.

Comment: @starkeen Ok, question updated

Comment: What url are you typing into browser and what happens?

Comment: `http://ip/projectname/config/index.php?p=example` or `http://ip/projectname/config/?p=example` . To test i put the .htaccess file in the project root and also on the config folder. Nothing happen, the url doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `/project/config/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/config/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /config/(?:index\.php)?\?p=([^\s&]+)&p2=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /config/(?:index\.php)?\?p=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&p2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. With this code the result is this : `ip/project/config/?p=page1` => `ip/config/page1?p=page1`

Comment: Ok now the rule works (in part), this is the result : `ip/project/config/?p=page1` => `ip/project/config/page1?p=page1`

Comment: The result should be this `ip/project/config/?p=page1` => `ip/project/config/page1/`

Comment: Hi, it's possible to modify the rule to handle a possible second parameter p2? If the parameter p2 is present `ip/project/config/?p=page1&p2=subpage1` => `ip/project/config/page1/subpage1`. I tried to modify the rule but not knowing well the grammar of the htaccess files i'm not succeeding in the intent.

Comment: Hi, it's possible to edit this rules adding also this rule : `ip/project/config/?p=page1&param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3` => `ip/project/config/page1/param1/param2` (hiding the param3) , keeping the two rules already present? I tried to change the rules, but i think they conflict with each other.

Comment: Hi! I have created another one :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038133/htaccess-rewrite-url-two-variable-to-directory