# Replace URL String using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to replace a string in my url from `?ref=` to `?tracking=`.

My url looks something like this:

`http://mywebsite.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=18_40&product_id=214232?ref=12345`

and I want the link to read:

`https://vaulteksafe.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=18_20&product_id=214282?tracking=12345`

Keep in mind that the url changes per page. So the only thing I want changed is `?ref`.

I'm familiar with the basics of .httaccess so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is even possible. I have tried other code I have found here on stack overflow such as `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`, but none of it worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or feedback to whether or not what I am trying to do is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I think the best (simplest) approach is given here by implementing this on PHP side:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables

Comment: So `path=18_40` is becoming `path=18_20` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=(.*)&path=(.*)&product_id=(.*)?ref=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?route=%1&path=%2&product_id=%3?tracking=%4
```